# R - issue with time_length

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm using the R package `lubridate` to calculate the difference between two dates in years. The code is working fine the vast majority of time, but seems to struggle when the day and month of the two dates are the same. For example:

```
#Specifying date 1
date1 <- as.Date("1993/04/01")

#Specifying date 2
date2 <- as.Date("2011/04/01")

#Calculating years between date 1 and date 2
years <- trunc(time_length(difftime(date2, date1), "years"))
```

This returns the following:

```
> years
[1] 17
```

Calculating by hand, the difference in years should be 18.

Can anyone advise on how I can correct this? Or if this is expected behaviour, how I can override it? Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Alice

Comment: Try using `round(time_length(...` instead of `trunc`. The time difference you're looking at is ~17.998, and `trunc` rounds down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using truncate. Use floor and this should override this behavior.

```
#Specifying date 1
date1 <- as.Date("1993/04/01")

#Specifying date 2
date2 <- as.Date("2011/04/01")

#Calculating years between date 1 and date 2
years <- floor(time_length(difftime(date2, date1), "years"))
years

##As mentioned in the comments, round also works
years_round <- round(time_length(difftime(date2, date1), "years"),0)
years_round

###A third possible approach
years_interval interval(date1, date2) %/% years(1)
years_interval
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However, `floor` still results in 17. I would use `round` as you also suggest, but that results in other time differences being rounded upwards (I am treating this object as an age variable in a later analysis, so for example 13 years and 8 months would still need to be considered age 13, rather than age 14). The problem seems to be that the `time_length` or `difftime` function is incorrectly calculating the difference as ~17.9986 years, rather than 18 years. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You could try a new approach. Will edit my answer. However, on my machine, the floor approaches works fine. What version of R are you using?

Comment: I'm running version 3.5.1, so perhaps that's the issue. But in any case, that third approach works perfectly - thank you!